# Openldap failover on RHEL

Tags: openldap, rhel, failover

How to implement OPENLDAP failover on RHEL. We have couple of LDAP servers, need to know how to handle failover of one server and redirect to other, viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on 2.3+, n-Way Multi Master with mirrormode enabled and a wide IP is an option. I found [this](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch7/#ol-syncrepl-mm) to be a helpful resource after exhausting the OpenLDAP documentation. Of course, this assumes that you want the data replicated and both servers to be available without caring which one you're actually connecting to.